# how to check if a listview is empty or not in javafx 8?

Tags: javafx

i have two listviews, the 'first listview' and the 'second listview'. i need to listen if 'first listview' is empty or not so that i could automatically setDisable(true) or setDisable(false) the 'second listview'. how to implement this using a listener?

Answer (score 2):

This can be very easily achieved with a single binding.

```
@FXML
private ListView<Foo> listViewFoo;
@FXML
private ListView<Bar> listViewBar;

listViewBar.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(listViewFoo.getItems()));
```

if you need the reverse, then you just switch `isEmpty()` out with `isNotEmpty()`.

Comment: Should work as long as the `ListView`s `items` list is not replaced but only modified...

Comment: @fabian Yup, if `setItems()` is expected to be called, then the binding would be much more complex, but definitely still possible.

Comment: so there is Bindings... works perfectly. should start to learn bindings.

Comment: @fabian, @Jai, in that case it can be used the `itemsProperty` in that binding. It is not as  complex :)

Comment: @Sunflame It is not so simple.. If you did that, you will not know when the `ObservableList` set in `setItems()` becomes empty. You need to add listener to `itemsProperty()`, which would add another listener (`ListChangeListener`) to the new `ObservableList`, and remove listener from old `ObservableList`. Well, unless `ListProperty` does become invalid when underlying `ObservableList` becomes invalid.

Comment: @Jai Hmm, yeah, at the first sight it seemed a bit easier, but as you said at least it is possible, to cover that part too :)